# Analog to digital converter IC

Tags: adc

I want 4 bit digital input for presetting of counter 74ls192.How can I do such task using Analog to digital converter? Is there any specific IC available for 4 bits ADC? Or do i need to design ADC using comparator and resistors?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't buy an off-the-shelf 4-bit ADC. But you can buy an 8-bit parallel-out ADC and just ignore the 4 lsb's of the output.

That will almost certainly be cheaper (in money, board area, and power) than building your own 4-bit ADC from comparators.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the four most-significant bits of an 8-bit ADC.

[image]

*Figure 1. 8-bit ADC with oscillator based on the [TI ADC0804](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc0804-n.pdf). Source: [Electro-Tech Online](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/idea-questions-voice-encryption-using-adc-dac.40785/).*